# elementor doesnt loop self-hosted video file

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want use full screen background video.

I uploaded to wordpress media and copied link and used link on section background video. There is not selection option is it youtube or vimeo or self-hosted video. It says "YouTube/Vimeo link, or link to video file (mp4 is recommended)." so I assume it should work with my video. But my video plays only once.

I can't use youtube link because it shows youtube icon and text.